# Splunk - Extract multiple values not equaling a value from a string

Tags: splunk

In Splunk I'm trying to extract multiple parameters and values that do not equal a specific word from a string. For example:

Anything in this field that does not equal "negative", extract the parameter and value:

Field:

```
field={New A=POSITIVE, New B=NEGATIVE, New C=POSITIVE, New D=BAD}
```

Result:

```
New A=POSITIVE
New C=POSITIVE
New D=BAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this search.  It uses a regular expression to extract parameters and values where the value is not "NEGATIVE".

```
index=foo
| rex field=field max_match=0 "(?<result>New \w=(?!NEGATIVE)\w+)"
| mvexpand result
```

Comment: To actually extract the field/value pairs, you may need to also look at the `extract` command, something like ``` | rename _raw as _orig_raw, result AS _raw
| extract pairdelim="," kvdelim="=" clean_keys=true
| rename _orig_raw as _raw ```

Comment: Ah, see my actual post below for something clearer to read :(

Answer (score 0):

To extract the actual field/value pairs, add this to the end of Rich's solution

```
| rename _raw as _orig_raw, result AS _raw
| extract pairdelim="," kvdelim="=" clean_keys=true
| rename _orig_raw as _raw
```